# Best practice for handling navigation to many ViewControllers which can be navigated to by many ViewControllers within an application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

The purpose of this question is to find the best practice for handling navigation to many ViewControllers, which can be navigated to by many other ViewControllers within an application. The app I'm working on at the moment does exactly this, I have 3 ViewControllers which can be navigated to by 3-4 other ViewControllers each. In the past I have always just written the navigation code in each ViewController as needed but now I'm thinking there might be a better, cleaner way to go about with less code required. I'm leaning towards creating a NavigationClass as explained below, but I would to hear other peoples thoughts on how to go about it.

I can think of 3 different ways to handle this, but I am wondering if anyone has any different ideas. The ways that I am thinking are:

**1. Creating a NavigationClass:**
The Navigation class could be imported into any of the ViewControllers which are access points. The NavigationClass would contain methods such as:

```
+(void)pushToDetailViewControllerWithObject:(MyObject *)obj fromNavigationController:(UINavigationController *)navController{
    DetailViewController *VC = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
    VC.object = obj;
    [navController pushToViewController:VC animated:true];
}
```

The navigation class would contain a similar function for every ViewController which has multiple access points.

**2. Just calling the methods from all ViewControllers**:
This is what I have been doing for a while, I feel that by doing this I am re-writing the same code over and over, and though some people may disagree with me, I am thinking that this is not the best solution.

**3. Storyboard segues and `prepareForSegue`**

I have never been to keen on StoryBoard segues as I am starting to use StoryBoards less these days, but I know that it's how some people like to do it.

Anyway, please let me know what you think about the NavigationClass, or if you have any better ways to go about it,

Cheers

Obj C or Swift answers welcome

Comment: I’ve decided to create a navigation helper class to handle navigation from within the application. I feel that this blue g post I stumbled upon helped me a lot http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2013/06/ios-app-architecture-and-tdd-1.html?m=1